# Laravel/Eloquent, retrieve data dynamically (whereIn, sum)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group, laravel-7

I am pretty noob in Laravel, and I would like to retrieve data from DB in an "automated" way. I have a query that get the value of key "cases" where 'state' is the latest repeated

```
$pieWyoming=State::select('cases')->where('state', '=', 'Wyoming')->orderByDesc('id')->limit(1)->get()->sum('cases');
```

But I want to do this with whereIn

```
$statesArr = array("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Guam", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virgin Islands", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming");

$Wyoming=State::select('cases')->whereIn('state',$statesArr)->orderByDesc('id')->limit(1)->get()->sum('cases');
```

But it seems that this traverse $statesArr and only gets the last value, that is correct but is only one value from one state, I want ALL VALUES from ALL states

**EDIT, SAMPLE DATA AND EXPECTED OUTPUT**

The database holds data as this https://res.cloudinary.com/dcdajhifi/image/upload/v1599003808/ex1_ys5ksi.png

and I would like to get only the value of field "cases" for each state in array $statesArr, each state should be the last repeated, in example
https://res.cloudinary.com/dcdajhifi/image/upload/v1599003808/ex2_lby8md.png

here is the last time ALABAMA appears, so I would like to get the value of cases for this row, THIS for each state. So I could create a pannel where I can display the state name with it's value cases and deaths, without doing a query for each state.

Comment: That is not the behavior of [whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses). whereIn() will match any value in the array provided.

Comment: try removing the limit() on whereIn statement

Comment: @KurtFriars but how can I save that match?

Comment: Are you wanting to get the latest row from each state in the array?

Comment: @Rwd Exactly, it is a CSV where states names repeat a lot but I want to get the last time it is repeated and from that row get the value of cases, this for each state

Comment: @joecort can you include sample data of states and also add the expected output for each state from the sample data set

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid sure, you can check my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pick the latest entry (based on latest **autoincrement** id) for each state you can do a self join with your table like

```
DB::table('states as a')
  ->select('a.*')
  ->leftJoin('states as b', function ($join) {
        $join->on('a.state', '=', 'b.state')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('a.id < b.id'))
             ;
   })
  ->whereNull('b.id')
  ->whereIn('a.state',$statesArr)
  ->get();
```

If you are using latest version of laravel you can rewrite above using inner join

```
$latestStates = DB::table('states')
                   ->select(DB::raw('max(id) as max_id'))
                   ->groupBy('state');

$states = DB::table('states as a')
        ->joinSub($latestStates, 'b', function ($join) {
            $join->on('a.id', '=', 'b.max_id');
        })->whereIn('a.state',$statesArr)
          ->get();
```

Or you can use `whereExists`

```
$states = DB::table('states as a')
           ->whereExists(function ($query) {
               $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                     ->from('states as b')
                     ->whereRaw('a.state= b.state')
                     ->groupBy('b.state')
                     ->havingRaw('max(b.id) = a.id')
                     ;
           })->whereIn('a.state',$statesArr)
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```php
$statesArr = array("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Guam", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virgin Islands", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming");

$Wyoming = State::whereIn('state', $statesArr)->orderByDesc('id')->sum('cases');
```

Comment: it throws this: Call to a member function whereIn() on float

Comment: @joecort Answer updated. I forgot that `sum` is like `get` so it hit DB on call.